# Wrap all subclasses methods inherited from abstract class with the same wrapper

Tags: python, class, exception, wrapper, abstract

I'm trying to wrap all subclasses (E, F) methods inherited from abstract class (D) with the **same exception_wrapper**.

I tried to wrap the abstract class methods and because the subclasses methods override the abstract methods they are not wrapped with the `exception_wrapper`.

how can I wrap all subclasses methods from the abstract class without declaring it from the subclasses?

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import functools


class D(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def b(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError

def exception_wrapper(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.loggerservice.info(str(ex))

    return func_wrapper

class E(D):
    @exception_wrapper
    def b(self, **kwargs):
        return 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I'll show how to access `D`'s subclasses and apply the wrapper. I've assumed you want to wrap all methods that have the same name as the ones decorated with `@abstractmethod` in `D`.

```
class D(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    ...

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        for name_of_func_to_wrap in D.__abstractmethod__:
            setattr(
                cls,
                name_of_func_to_wrap,
                exception_wrapper(
                    cls.__dict__[name_of_func_to_wrap]
                )
            )
```

### `__init_subclass__`

Called right after a subclass of D is defined which suits this problem nicely.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation

### Selecting Methods to Wrap

`@abstractmethod` is a very simple decorator. It just adds an attribute to the function and returns it. ABCMeta then looks for this marker and creates `__abstractmethod__` to track them. It is trivial to create your own decorator and to be more selective in which functions are wrapped.

### Further Enhancements

This will fail if direct subclass does not implement all abstract methods. If that is handled appropriately it will still not handle defining new abstract methods in subclasses.